# Heroku DNS: point subdomain to folder (Rails)

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain, cname

I have a subfolder (domain.com/folder) and I'd like to create an Alias (CNAME) for it of folder.domain.com. However, I seem to be unable to find the relevant documentation.

Any hints or suggestions?

Thanks,
Nick.

**EDIT**

```
constraints :subdomain => "connect" do
  scope :module => "connect" do
     # all the stuff i want to be in the subdomain
  end
end
```

Getting `uninitialized constant Connect` using `http://connect.lvh.me:3000/apps` and `No route matches [GET] "/apps"` for `http://connect.localhost:3000/apps`

What's going on here?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160328/api-subdomain-for-heroku-app-is-it-possible)?

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't exactly working like I had hoped. I have `constraints :subdomain => "connect" do
  scope :module => "connect" do` but then I get a "no route matches" error for every route except `root`, which is outside of the `do` blocks. Check the edit