# Specifying a subdomain in the route definition in Express

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

I'm new to ExpressJS and NodeJS in general, so I need directions on how to achieve this effect:

```
app.get('/', 'sub1.domain.com', function(req, res) { 
    res.send("this is sub1 response!"); 
});

app.get('/', 'sub2.domain.com', function(req, res) {
    res.send("this is sub2 response!");
}
```

So that when I request `sub1.domain.com` the first handler reacts and on `sub2.domain.com` I get response from second handler. I've read some questions on SO about using vhost for this purpose, but I'd be more happy if what I described above worked rather than creating multiple server instances like in vhost.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791260/how-can-i-configure-multiple-sub-domains-in-express-js-or-connect-js/23324995#23324995

Answer (score 10):

A quick and simple solution is:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  var hostname = req.headers.host.split(":")[0];

  if(hostname == "sub1.domain.com")
    res.send("this is sub1 response!");
  else if(hostname == "sub2.domain.com")
    res.send("this is sub2 response!");

});
```

Reference:

http://code4node.com/snippet/http-proxy-with-custom-routing

Answer (score 8):

Or you can simply use npm package [subdomain](https://npmjs.org/package/subdomain), it take cares of your subdomain routes. Also similar to that you can check out Wilson's project on [subdomain-handler](https://github.com/wilsonpage/express-subdomain-handler).