# Sub domains on ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I am developing an application with ExpressJS. And i want to use sub domains on this application.(Virtual subdomains)

Is there any way to interprete this url;

```
http://customer_name.mysite.com
```

as

```
http://mysite.com/customer_name
```

My current url mapping on cntroller like this;

```
app.get('/:customer_name/?', function(req, res, next) {
//something functions
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have answered a similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791260/how-can-i-configure-multiple-sub-domains-in-express-js-or-connect-js/23324995#23324995

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added wildcard domain on my domain provider(GoDaddy). You can refer [here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names) for how to add wildcard domain

And then, i have prepared a middleware that parses url and get subdomain part. Query subdomain text as user that's all.

For getting subdomain, you can refer [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.11/api/os.html#os.hostname). Simply get host name and split it. First one is the subdomain name.

Comment: Could you give some details on how you did the first  part. Did you add A record or CName?

Comment: @MaxPain I have added CNAME record.

Comment: So I added a CNAME at Godaddy host name just * and made it points to mycoolapp.parseapp.com, do I need to change anything on parse.com? Right I have the host name set to www.mycoolapp.com.

Comment: When I added the CName record, I am getting this message now when I try to access something like hi.mycoolapp.com

Parse App not found
We don't seem to have an app at this host name.
It might not be configured correctly, or may have moved.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly the usecase of the [express-subdomains](https://github.com/tblobaum/express-subdomains) module.

Your require it, tell it the subdomains and all requests on these subdomains are available as prefixes to your routes.

For example

> customer_name.mysite.com/route

would be mapped to

> mysite.com/customer_name/route

Comment: However, i cannot tell the domain names to express. Since, when a user create an accoutn, also virtual subdomains created. There is no physical subdomain

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs has nothing to do with these stuff. That's what the server is meant to handle with. Node just listens to a port and that's it. It's your job to forward any host to that port. So, I guess you should play with your server setup.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As you said i have nothing to do on nodejs side, i should do it on domain setups.