# How do I route sub domains in Node.js without Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791260/how-can-i-configure-multiple-sub-domains-in-express-js-or-connect-js/23324995#23324995) explain how to route sub domains in Node.js *with* Express.

I want to know how to do it without Express.

Here's my server module, which returns a server object:

```
module.exports.serve = function(port) {
    var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {

        // Parse & process URL
        var reqInfo = url.parse(req.url, true, true), 
            path    = reqInfo.pathname;
        debug.log("Client [" +  req.connection.remoteAddress + 
                "]requesting resource: " + path);

        // Quickly handle preloaded requests
        if (preloaded[path])
            preloadReqHandler(req, res, preloaded[path], path);

        // Handle general requests
        else generalReqHandler(req, res, reqInfo);
    }).listen(port);
    return server;
};
```

No need to go into detail with the modules that handle the requests, I'm just interested in how to detect `www.example.com` and route it to `example.com` or vice-versa, via my server.

---

Just to add as much detail as possible, my goal here is to route all traffic from `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` and send it all to `https://example.com`. To do that, I think I just need to learn how to route the `www` sub domain, and then listen on both the `http` and `https` ports for that routing.

Comment: I am not expert in this, so not writing this as an answer, but if you aren't using express, you can just check if it doesn't start with https://example.com return a 302 with https://example.com, and then all will be redirected quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since HTTP 1.1, user agents send the `Host` request header which specifies the domain. So you can get the domain (including the port if specified) from `req.headers['host']` and apply your custom domain routing logic.

If you're talking with a HTTP 1.0 or older user agent, then just reply with "505 HTTP Version Not Supported" or serve some default content.