# Subdomain handling in MEAN stack app

Tags: mean-stack

I have a web application. Let's say it is live on **www.abc.com**, now I want to create admin panel for this web app. So is it possible to use sub-domain like **admin.abc.com** and how can I handle this in MEAN stack application.

Comment: I've just found for you [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5792397/7564182), hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.:)