# NodeJS Routing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

how can I route below url to different view in node.js

http://admin.localhost:3000/users/customer/view

and

http://localhost:3000/users/customer/view

currently it go to the same route that I set for

> http://localhost:3000/users/customer/view

**App.js**

```
....

var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);

....
```

**Users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/Customer/Create', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('customer', {});
});

router.get('/Customer/View', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('customer', {});
});

router.get('/Employee/Create', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('customer', {});
});

router.get('/Employee/View', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('customer', {});
});

module.exports = router;
```

and what is the terminology for doing something like this with your url by adding admin before url admin.yoururl.com ?

Comment: You should have `sub-domain`

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791260/how-can-i-configure-multiple-sub-domains-in-express-js-or-connect-js

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using express, you can use the express middleware [express-subdomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain).

The package even supports multi level subdomains like v1.api.domain.com.

You need to create one Router per subdomain and then bind that Router to your express app using the package:

```js
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

//api specific routes 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to our API!');
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.json([
    { name: "Brian" }
  ]);
});

app.use(subdomain('api', router));
app.listen(3000);
```