# How to install dependencies for subfolder during AWS CodePipeline deploy?

Tags: express, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to organize my ExpressJS app, [like the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791260/how-can-i-configure-multiple-sub-domains-in-express-js-or-connect-js) here. (I don't use subdomains, just subfolders) Currently my folder structure is like

> root (expressjs project with its own package.json)
>   --api (expressjs project with its own package.json)
>   --panel (single page app)
>   --site (single page app)
>   package.json (root folders package.json)
>   app.js (root folders app.js)

My app.js at the root level is like

```
express()
.use(helmet())
.use(compression())
.use('/api', require('./api/app').app)
.use('/panel', express.static('./panel'))
.use('/', express.static('./site'))
.listen(port);
```

My app.js at the api project end with

```
exports.app = app;
```

I use Github to store my project and CodePipeline to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk. But it does not work, the EB instance is red. This is from the logs: (cors is a dependency of api project)

```
Error: Cannot find module 'cors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/api/app.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
module.js:471
    throw err;
```

So my question is this, how can I install dependencies of subfolders during CodePipeline deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "cd api && npm install"
},
```

and a .npmrc file with

> unsafe-perm = true

in it