# What do we call this type of naming of url i.e account.example.com and blog.example.com

Tags: node.js, express

Assist me on how to achieve nodejs particulary expressjs framework. I want to have a website that can be structured with urls belonging to site as below:

- store.example.com
- account.example.com
- learn.example.com
- services.example.com

I can not figure out how to configure such mechanism in express.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure multiple sub domains in Express.js or Connect.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791260/how-can-i-configure-multiple-sub-domains-in-express-js-or-connect-js)

Comment: If it's all in 1 express application these are often called vhosts.

Answer (score 0):

First, from your command line, run:

```
npm install vhost
```

Then, in your express code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const vhost = require("vhost");

app.use(vhost("store.example.com", function(req, res, next) {
  /*
  handle requests to store.example.com here
  */
}

app.use(vhost("account.example.com", function(req, res, next) {
  /*
  handle requests to account.example.com here
  */
}
```

Btw, such urls are called subdomains, the part before the "extension" (.com, .net etc.) is called second level domain (SLD) and the last part is called top level domain (TLD).